# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly - SB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Last week I quite suddenly got this error while building Xamarin.Android for release. Last time I built the project for release everything worked fine.

The projects builds when I choose to link no assemblies, but when I use “Link SDK assemblies only” it fails. And it fails across every branch I have. I have tried to build my master-branch that has not changed since before last time i worked, and that also fails now.

I have also tried to delete bin & obj and checked Android versions and that packages match

Visual Studio is updated, and also have re-installed it, also re-installed Xamarin and Android SDK.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2145,5): error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamrin.Android.Common.targets(2145,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly ‘ProjectName.Droid, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: Have you tried to  set the linking to `None`?

Comment: Then it does build and run, but it is not a solution. The app would be to big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>` from the android.csproj-file. The problem was that the linker tried linkage before the packages got prepared for linking.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

I've got an answer from a Xamarin.Android contributor who explained what has happened to the build process.
The "SignAndroidPackage" MSBuild target no longer depends on the "Build" target so, I think, it implicates if an Android project has "DefaultTargets" set to only "SignAndroidPackage" then this target won't be able to find the project compiled DLL since it was not built.
Thus I assume that this is why we have "LinkAssemblies" task failed.

**To resolve the error I've added the "Build" target just before "SignAndroidPackage".**[image]

## Old comment

I've faced the same error in my project after migrating to Visual Studio 2019.
Everything is fine in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio for Mac. Thus I presumed that it might be a bug and raised an issue on GitHub.

We may both follow it here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3715

Comment: shouldn't it be a comment rather than answer?

Comment: @AlexanderLysenko, I'll be happy to do so but my reputation is too low :)

Comment: Ok - just make sure when you do have the necessary Reputation to post those as comments in the future

Comment: I surely will! Thanks for understanding!